# Google Script - get a text with an apostrophe in a cell (Spreadsheet) and search for it in a body of Google Doc

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, re2

I did a script (container-bound script) in my Spreadsheet in which I have 4 columns: (1) text before, (2) text after, (3) text to insert between, and (4) a URL of a Google Doc with the text in which I want to replace with the right value (between).

My method replace is not working when I have an apostrophe (') I didn't tried for other characters(/," so I don't know). How to solve this? 
[image]
This is my code:

```
var COLUMN_URL =....

var URL = ...;
// loop for n
Logger.log(' URL ' + URL);
var body = DocumentApp.openByUrl(URL).getBody();
body.replaceText(
  sheet.getRange(n + 1, 2).getDisplayValue() + ".*" + sheet.getRange(n + 1, 3).getDisplayValue(), 
  sheet.getRange(n + 1, 2).getDisplayValue() + sheet.getRange(n + 1, 4).getDisplayValue() +
  sheet.getRange(n + 1, 3).getDisplayValue()
);
```

Edit : I've tested with several symbols when I don't use the **apostrophes,quotes, * and ?** it works i will test with other symbols but for now the ! & . and numbers placed in the cells (before and after) are working

With **\, (** and **)** I get a message invalid regular expression pattern I love .*McDonald)s

Comment: You should share some examples of the evaluated arguments to the `replace` function

Comment: @tehhowch thank you very much I've put a photo tell me if it's still unclear so I can edit it :) and for the logs i have the right values :) with apostrophes^^

Comment: Better, but you should share the evaluated arguments, not just the source of the evaluated arguments. i.e. `var textParts = sheet.getRange(n+1, 2, 1, 3).getDisplayValues(); Logger.log(textParts);`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand share the evaluated arguments what do you mean? I've edited the post the logs i've tested it's with ' so I think it's ok  when I don't use the apostrophes,quotes, * and ? it works  i will test with other charactersand edit the post after

Comment: My guess is you will need to write a parser function that checks for values which should be escaped, in order to prevent interpreting them as regex control characters

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer the characters that aren't working I have the >>   " ; ' ; * ; ? and for the error of invalid regular expression pattern I have \ ; ( ; ) for the function there is not a more simple way from a library/or an option I don't know how to write this parse function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `\Q...\E`[¹](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)

```
var textBfr = sheet.getRange(n + 1, 2).getDisplayValue(),
   textAr = sheet.getRange(n + 1, 3).getDisplayValue(),
   textInsert = sheet.getRange(n + 1, 4).getDisplayValue();
    body.replaceText( "\\Q"+textBfr+"\\E"+ ".*?" +"\\Q"+textAr+"\\E", textBfr+textInsert+textAr);
```